# How to access index within Array.from() function

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to pass array index value to the func using `Array.from`

I have this code

```
    const g = (length, func) => {
      return Array.from({ length }, func);
    };

const getData = () => { /*do work*/ }

g(getData())
```

I want to be able to pass index to my `getData()` func

```
    const g = (length, func) => {
      return Array.from({ length }, func(index));
    };

const getData = (index) => { return { id: index } }
```

Is it possible to achieve that within `Array.from()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter passed to the `Array.from` callback will be the index being iterated over. So either change the function you're passing in to accept a second parameter

```js
const g = (length, func) => {
  return Array.from({ length }, func);
};
const getData = (_, index) => { return { id: index } }

console.log(g(3, getData));
```

or, if you want it to be the first parameter, use an anonymous inline function to call it with the index inside `Array.from`.

```js
const g = (length, func) => {
  return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => func(i));
};
const getData = (index) => { return { id: index } }

console.log(g(3, getData));
```

Comment: interesting, can you explain how it words or point out to the right direction? Is it some sort of iterator feature in all arrays in JavaScript `(_, index)` ? It is quite clear how it works in the second example, but the first one is quite hard to understand.

Comment: `_` is just a convention often used to indicate an unused argument. Could also be `(unusedArg, index) =>`. The first snippet is also equivalent to `.from({ length }), (_, i) => func(_, i))` - but specifying the same parameters a callback takes again is repetitive and unnecessary, so you may as well just do `.from({ length }, func)`

Comment: I really still confused how in the first example `index` getting passed through to `getData` function `const getData = (_, index) => { return { id: index } }`

Comment: It's just a function that's passed directly instead of being expanded out into one that's inline that calls another. `(a, b) => callback(a, b)` can almost always be substituted with just `callback` unless a third argument is needed. Same for `(a, b, c) => callback(a, b, c)` and so on.